# Short queries return not enough results

Tags: elasticsearch

Hey I have a field in elasticsearch that is analyzed with the alphanumeric_analyzer. Then I index data into that field that looks like this:

Test-00001

Test-00002

to

Test-01000

If I execute the following query, I get 250 results consistently. But they aren't necessarily Test-00001 to Test -00250.

```
`{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "filename_Analyzed": {
        "type": "phrase_prefix",
        "query": "0"
      }
    }
  }
}`
```

I was expecting to get 1000 results, but I only get 250. Are my expectations correct, or is the search incorrect?

EDIT 1:

Gist for the mapping:
https://gist.github.com/goalie7960/8ffd1536269a901f18bc

EDIT 2:

If I double the number of shards, the number of results also doubles. So 5 shards = 250 results, 10 shards = 500 results, etc.

EDIT 3:

Here's a gist for the analyzer I am using. But I can also reproduce with the standard analyzer.

https://gist.github.com/goalie7960/b0bbbddf1cee29b4b5ed

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Your title says "short queries return no results" yet you say that you get 250 results consistently. Don't understand what problem you  are having. I'd suggest you clean up the question, add your mapping, sample data, sample output and expected output.

Comment: I've tried to clean it up, hope it makes sense now.

Comment: I'd add the mapping and the output you are receiving. You say you are getting 250 back - are they the same 250 each time? Are they random? The first 250?

Comment: I will add the mappings and the output. They are the same 250, but it might be the first 100, then skip 1, then 50 more consecutive, etc. It is consistently random?

Comment: I've never heard of the "alphanumeric_analyzer" - is this a custom analyzer?

Comment: Oh sorry, it's a pattern analyzer, lowercased = true, and pattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9]".

Comment: What do you mean by 'doubling the number of shards', by the way?

Comment: So if I run my tests with 5 shards, I get a certain result. If I double the shards to 10, and run the test again, I get double the original result.

Comment: you need to add the exact mappings and custom analyzers you are using - leaving that info out makes it impossible to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Just posted the analyzer, I thought I had posted the mappings previously. If that's not correct let me know plz.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the prefix query or phrase prefix was exceeding the max expansion limit in elastic search. A non simple solution was to switch to ngram analysis and it has fixed the problem. Yay.